# How to kill interactive shell and process/jobs running on it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, interactive

I'm using docker container interactive shell to executed the command on the shell.

```
e.g. docker exec -i docker_container_name sh
```

and I launch commands on this interactive shell. Now If I want to kill the this interactive shell and command running on it, How to do that?

I tried sending  `kill -9 shell_pid or kill -s 15 shell_pid` signal to interactive shell. However in this case interactive shell gets killed but the command running on interactive shell is till there and  becomes orphan process.

Please let me know how to kill interactive shell with command running on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the child(ren) processes first, before killing the shell and kill them too

```
CPIDS=`pgrep -P $shellpid` # gets pids of child processes
kill -9 $shellpid
for cpid in $CPIDS ; do kill -9 $cpid ; done
```

Or alternatively (this isn't as safe, because, if running series of commands in shell, next one may be called between those two kill commands)

```
pkill -TERM -P $shellpid # sends TERMINATE signal to children
kill -9 $shellpid
```